# Has there ever been an expert system (i.e. computer program) developed for answering simple halachic queries?

Tags: technology, shulchan-aruch

As a computer programmer and student of the Torah, I've conceptualized the idea of codifying halacha - quite literally - in an expert system, allowing one to submit halachic queries and receive answers to them. This of course would only be done for my own educational benefit both as a computer and torah learner (as clearly such a system bears no halachic authority and would be very simplistic in its *paskining* abilities).

I'd do this as a supplement to my learning *shulchan aruch* - a great way to inculcate into myself the connections and relationships between laws.

I'm wondering if anyone has done something like this in the past?

Comment: welcome Akiva,  welcome to Mi Yodeya. a greet Idea. A big project.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  What an interesting idea.  Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.  I look forward to seeing you around the site.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6008/3